About a property of solutions to the delay equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax(t) + F(t,\,x_t)$ in a Banach space $E$
I'm dealing with the equation \begin{equation*} \tag{1} \frac{dx}{dt} = Ax(t) + F(t, \, x_t),\end{equation*} in which $A$ is the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $(T(t))_{t \, \geqslant \, 0}$ on a Banach space $E$, $x \colon [-\,r, \, 0] \longrightarrow E$ is continuous, and $F \colon \, \mathbb{R} \times \mathscr{B} \longrightarrow E$ is Lipschitz continuous and linear in it's second variable. 
The aforementioned space $\mathscr{B}$ can be considered as being $C([- \, r, \, 0], \, E)$ under the sup norm, and the functions history $x_t$ are defined as $x_s(\theta) = x(s + \theta)$, for all $\theta \in [- \, a, \, 0]$. 
It can be proven that, for all $\phi \in \mathscr{B}$, there exists an unique mild solution of the form \begin{equation} x(t) = T(t - \sigma) \, \phi(0) + \int_\sigma^t T(t - s) \, F(s, \, x_s) \, \mathrm{d} s, \quad t \in [\sigma, \, \sigma + a],
\end{equation} such that $x_\sigma = \phi$ for the equation $(1)$, $a > 0$. We denote this solution as $x( \, \cdot \, ) = x( \, \cdot \,, \, \sigma, \, \phi, \, F)$. 
Therefore, I need to prove the following property: \begin{equation} x( t \,, \, \sigma, \, \phi, \, F) = x( t \,, \, \tau, \, x_\tau(\sigma, \, \phi, \, F), \, F), \quad \sigma < \tau. \end{equation} Considering $u = x( t \,, \, \tau, \, x_\tau(\sigma, \, \phi, \, F), \, F)$, one has \begin{equation} 
u(t) = T(t - \tau) \, x_\tau(0, \, \sigma, \, \phi, \, F) + \int_\tau^t T(t - s) \, F(s, \, x_s) \, \mathrm{d} s, \end{equation} and, by some manipulations (by identifying the original solution in the formula and splitting the integral), I think the desired equality can be proved. 
However, the article I'm reading doesn't bother to elaborate, and so I'm a little lost, because I don't know if this approach is sufficient or even necessary (I'm wondering if there's an easier way to tackle this).
Any help is appreciated, this is haunting me for a while now.

Can you structure a bit more the question in order to know : what is your problem and its context then what are your attempts and  your question ?

Check something called the semigroup property.
